# Multi month selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anybody know whats the name of the multi-month selector control used in Mint.com?

I have a video of it been used [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=p3ceNFLLR3E). I've come across a lot of date picker and calendar controls but all of them are pretty much the same.

Preferably in jQuery

Comment: You mean the month slide-selector thingy at the top?  I would guess that is custom code.

Comment: There is no plugin that provides that functionality like in this video ! You will have to do in on your own.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll just build that myself.

Answer (score 0):

How about [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)? Its widely used and well tested.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is a control from Qlik softwares (either Qlik Sense or QlikView) that allows users to do such selections. It can be embedded into Mint's solution.

Here's an example:

My Life in Data - Tab Running: https://eu-b.demo.qlik.com/QvAJAXZfc/opendoc.htm?document=qvdocs%2FMy%20Life%20in%20Data.qvw&host=demo11
[image: Month Selector - My Life in Data]

Note that it is really hard to make sure as the video is not 'browsable'.